# How to simplify CSS?

Tags: css

I wanted to know if there's a way I can simplify this CSS code, I'm doing it in WordPress:

```
#cont1:hover h3{color:#fff;}
#cont1:hover p{color:#fff;}
#cont1:hover i{color:#fff;}

#cont2:hover h3{color:#fff;}
#cont2:hover p{color:#fff;}
#cont2:hover i{color:#fff;}

#cont3:hover h3{color:#fff;}
#cont3:hover p{color:#fff;}
#cont3:hover i{color:#fff;}
```

I already tried to use a comma (..hover h3, p, i{...}) but it didn't work, and I don't even know how to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use ids for whatever reason then you can do this in one line of CSS like so using the [:where() pseudo selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/w/where/) but as Ron says, it's easier just to plonk a class in your relevant html:

```
:where(#cont1, #cont2, #cont3):hover :where(h3, p, i) {color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group all those selectors into

```
[id^="cont"]:hover :where(h3, p, i) {color:#fff;}
```

to match any `h3, p, i` inside an hovered element whose id is starting with `cont` (instead of listing all `#cont1, #cont2, #cont3`...)

Answer (score 0):

instead of id's (#) use class (.), and apply that to your elements..

```css
.cont1:hover h3,.cont1:hover p,.cont1:hover i {color: #ffffff;}
```

or even:

```css
.cont1:hover :where(h3, p, i){color: #ffffff;}
```

We also do not know your exact structure, so we can only guess what is the best way to simplify your CSS

Comment: Even better: .cont1:hover :where(h3, p, i) or .cont1:hover :is(h3, p, i)